# Nome dos Drawables em uma lista de todos os drawables kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Está é a minha classe, aqui faço uma chamada com todos os Drawables, Mas no momento em que eu faço "drawableList.toString()" ele me retorna o nome como "android.graphics.drawable.bitmap@65vd6f5" e eu gostaria que o retorno fosse "R.drawable.icon_outline_airplane"

class IconComponenteRecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<IconComponenteRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

```
var drawableList = getAllDrawables().filter { it.toString().startsWith("android.graphics.drawable.") }

private fun getAllDrawables(): List<Drawable?> {
    return R.drawable::class.java.fields.map {
        ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, it.getInt(null), null)
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): IconComponenteRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.icon_component_card, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return drawableList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: IconComponenteRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemTitle.text = drawableList[position].toString().removePrefix("android.graphics.drawable.")
    holder.itemImage.setImageDrawable(drawableList[position])

    Log.d("Image - XXXXXX", drawableList.toString())
}

inner class ViewHolder(itemView : View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    var itemImage : ImageView
    var itemTitle : TextView

    init {
        itemImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_icon_component)
        itemTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_icon_name)

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que está sendo retornado, basicamente é o `toString` do objeto `Drawable`.
Para fazer o que você quer, você precisa pegar o nome do field no momento em que você está fazendo o `map`.

Seria algo assim:

```kotlin
private fun getAllDrawables(): List<Pair<String,Drawable?>> {
    return R.drawable::class.java.fields.map {
        it.name to try { 
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, it.getInt(null), null) 
        } catch (e: Exception) { null }
    }
}
```

Perceba que agora está sendo retornada uma lista de `Pair<String,Drawable?>`. Onde o primeiro elemento do `Pair` é nome do recurso e o `Drawable` é o segundo elemento.

Finalmente, para obter a lista, você pode usar:

```kotlin
val drawableList = getAllDrawables().filter {
    val (name, drawable) = it
    drawable != null // filtrando apenas os items com um Drawable válido
}
```

Finalmente, no seu adapter, use a uma `List<Pair<String,Drawable>>` no lugar de uma `List<Drawable>`.